# check for string in txt file on remote server

Tags: php

Hey guys im trying to search for the word `Error` in different subfolders on a remote Server. To enter the subfolders i use a variable in the path. My code is not working it always outputs `Not Found`, but for testing i inserted in a few .txt files the Word `ERROR`. So whats wrong with my Code?

```
$file_to_check = 'file://Bgsttc11/Backup/'.$stask[$j][1].'/log.txt';
            echo $path_to_check.'<br>';
            if (strstr($path_to_check, 'ERROR')) {
            echo 'found<br>';
            } 
            else {
            echo 'not found<br>';
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos) for case insensitive and if the string exists, and you are checking the file name and not contents:

```
$file_to_check = '\\\\bgsttc11\\Backup\\'.$stask[$j][1].'\\log.txt';
$position = stripos(implode('', file($path_to_check)), 'ERROR');
if ($position !== false) {
    echo 'found at position '.$position.'<br />';
} else {
    echo 'not found<br />';
}
```

Comment: i tried something similar but than i got an error tha file_get_contents is not able to check files on a remote server

Comment: gives this error `Warning: file() [function.file]: remote host file access not supported, `

Comment: add 3 `///` after file, updated answer, check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php)

Comment: `$position` isn't the line number here, is it?

Comment: `file:///` ends in this error: `Warning: file(file:///Bgsttc11/Backup/NE00TC0003/log.txt) [function.file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't know how your files systems are, check how you can open the file first.

Comment: When i use `file` with two // i can enter the file from browser the url changes than to: `\\bgsttc11\Backup\NE00TC0003\log.txt`

Comment: then use `\\bgsttc11\Backup\NE00TC0003\log.txt`

Comment: I have an problem with this because when i make this: `'\\'.$stask[$j][0].'\Backup\'.$stask[$j][1].'\log.txt'`the \ after Backup destroys the code in Notepad++ everything after it gets greyed out.